# How to check the KAFKA health in my situation

Tags: kubernetes

Our application is built on top of K8S Cluster, that is to manage large amount of devices. One of the feature is, if any device becomes offline, a notification would be triggered and an email would be sent out to the user.

But, since 2 weeks ago, such feature no longer works, and emails are not sent.

And since the guy used to work on the kafka part has left the company, I need to figure out if kafka service is still working health myself.

I am quite new to kafka, when I login the master node on k8s, I have see such pods that kafka related.

```
k8s -n kafka get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-0                           1/1     Running   779        466d
kafka-1                           1/1     Running   848        2y266d
kafka-2                           1/1     Running   797        466d
kafka-exporter-58c76747c6-j2cv2   1/1     Running   306        292d
kafka-manager-844657d4bf-q2j7n    1/1     Running   1647       2y215d
kafka-zookeeper-0                 1/1     Running   574        466d
kafka-zookeeper-1                 1/1     Running   573        2y266d
kafka-zookeeper-2                 1/1     Running   569        466d
```

Where should I start any type of sanity checking on Kafka service

Comment: Removed kafka tags. The given answers apply to any k8s service. You have `Status == Running` as shown. Beyond that, look at logs.

Answer (score 1):

You have both `kafka-exporter` and `kafka-manager` services.

Both of these have their own ability to check the health of Kafka via HTTP requests, either to the exporter's metrics endpoint (or Prometheus / Grafana, if these also exist in your cluster), or to the kafka-manager UI, rather than Kafka itself, and are not specific to kubectl commands.

More information

- https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter
- https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK (previously known as kafka-manager)

Alternatively, you could migrate to an installation of https://strimzi.io , which comes with its own monitoring stack based on Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

You can check pod logs with this command:

```
$ kubectl logs -n kafka [POD_NAME]
```

and you can check pod resource usage you can use this:

```
$ kubectl describe pod [POD_NAME] -n kafka
```

These two commands can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the check is done in an k8s idiomatic way then an liveness probe is used:

Execute:

```
kubectl get pod <pod name> -o yaml
```

and search for `livenessProbe`.